# File permissions on Linux Docker container running on a Windows host

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers, user-permissions

I have a general question regarding permissions between a windows host and a linux based container.

Assume I have an ubuntu container called BUILD and it is running on a Windows host.

BUILD is supposed to create a bunch of files in /tmp/data.

/tmp/data is however mounted from the host filesystem. The container Dockerfile has this:

```
...
VOLUME ["/tmp/data"]
...
```

and the container was started like so:

```
docker run -v C:\tmp\data:/tmp/data -d --name BUILDER BUILDER_IMAGE
```

I want the files created in C:\tmp\data to only be accessible to a specific windows user and / or group. How can I make sure that the files created by BUILD have the user permissions I want in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're building your Docker container, adding the line

```bash
USER username
```

would change the default user of the docker container (to the user named `username`).

However, you should ensure that the user `username` actually has write permissions to the mounted volume.

You can then run your Docker run commands with the flag `-u username` to have the new files created in the mounted directory belong to `username`.

```bash
docker run -v C:\tmp\data:/tmp/data -d --name -u username BUILDER BUILDER_IMAGE
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you!